# Sum up column of texboxes and display in textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## **Problem:**

I have to display the sum of the amount textboxes in the grid and display the total in the 'Bill Amount' text box, but all I am getting is 0. I have attached the screenshot for better understanding.

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

## **Source Code:**

**Html Code:**

```js
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function() {
  $('.Qty').on("input change", function() {
    var price = 0;
    var total = 0;

    $('.tb3 tr').each(function() {
      var qty = $(this).find('.Qty').val();
      var rate = $(this).find('.Rate').val();
      var price = qty * rate;
      $(this).find('.Value').val(price);
      total = total + price;
    });
    $('.TieTotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
  });

  $('.Value').on(function() {
    $('.tb3 tr').each(function() {});
    $('.TieTotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
  });


});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove3'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Product_Code" name="Prdtcode[]" class="form-control input- 
                 xs Product_Code " required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Product_Name" name="Prdtname[]" class="form- 
               control input-xs">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Qty" name="Qty[]" class="form-control input-xs" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Rate" class="form-control input- 
              xs" name="Rate[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Value" class="form-control input- 
               xs" name="amount[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove3'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Product_Code" name="Prdtcode[]" class="form-control input- 
                 xs Product_Code " required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Product_Name" name="Prdtname[]" class="form- 
               control input-xs">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Qty" name="Qty[]" class="form-control input-xs" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Rate" class="form-control input- 
              xs" name="Rate[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Value" class="form-control input- 
               xs" name="amount[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove3'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Product_Code" name="Prdtcode[]" class="form-control input- 
                 xs Product_Code " required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Product_Name" name="Prdtname[]" class="form- 
               control input-xs">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Qty" name="Qty[]" class="form-control input-xs" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Rate" class="form-control input- 
              xs" name="Rate[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="Value" class="form-control input- 
               xs" name="amount[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">BILL TOTAL:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control 
                 input-xs" name="tot" class="TieTotal" value="">
  </div>
```

I dont know what changes need to be done to fix this, please help me.

Comment: There's no onchange handler on input class Qty?

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]. You are missing lots of function definitions (`doit_onkeypress()`, `movetoNext()` etc). Either include these or remove them from your example so that we can run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Your each input have 2 class make sure to visit your 'tr td input'.

2)And if you need any change in code, just ask

```
//script
$(document).on('change', 'tr td:nth-child(6), tr td:nth-child(5), tr td:nth-child(4)', function(){
    var total = 0;
    var tr = $(this).parent();
    var qty = tr.find('td:nth-child(4)').find('input').val();
    var rate = tr.find('td:nth-child(5)').find('input').val();
    var amount = qty*rate;
    tr.find('td:nth-child(6)').find('input').val(amount);

    var tbody = tr.parent();

    $(tbody).find('tr').each(function(){
        total += Number($(this).find('td:nth-child(6)').find('input').val());          
    });

    $('.TieTotal').val(total);
})
```

Comment: still i am getting bill total value as 0

Comment: bro you have two class in single input. that why you are getting 0 and i have run your code on my end and it works perfectly. your each input have two 'class attribute', make it one

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="TieTotal" class="form-control 
                 input-xs" name="tot" value="">

Comment: make it like this----    <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="TieTotal form-control input-xs" name="tot" value="">

Comment: please mark as correct and useful answer if it is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a shot in your javascript code. This can go outside your `$(document).ready` function.

```
$('body').on('blur', '.Value', UpdateTotal);

function UpdateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    var $changeInputs = $('.Value');
    $changeInputs.each(function(idx, el) {
      total += Number($(el).val());
      });

  $('.TieTotal').val(total);
  //if the above doen't work try, but I don't know it will work since this here-> is a jQuery solution $('.TieTotal').attr("value",total); 
}
```

Comment: Whats the output? still 0? 

Also have you opened up the browser debugger to walk through the code to see if the values are being read or being added up?

Comment: Okay, just give me some time and I will try to come up with a solution. Have you reviewed the comments on your post btw?